# Facebook App that extracts Insights Data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am a sociologist working on a Facebook app as part of a new study I am conducting of how the posts of non-profit organizations go viral.

I have limited but not awful programming skills, and hired someone to write an app that extracts insights data from each organization (after user authentication, of course) and then mails a csv to an email account. The app used to get all the available data from the Graph API, but as of 3 weeks ago it started to only extract the three most recent days of data.

Here is the call I am using in the app:

# Get Insights data
    # insights = myfbfunctions.graph_api_call(access_token, oid, 'insights', {'since': date, 'until': date+datetime.timedelta(1)})
    start_date, end_date = self.GetPeriod(access_token, oid)
    today = datetime.datetime.now().date()

```
# Prepare output
result = ['name,%s,url,%s' % (name, url), 'object_id,metric,end_time,period,value']

insights = myfbfunctions.graph_api_call(access_token, oid, 'insights',\
        {'period': 86400 , 'end_time': start_date})

temp_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(insights['data'][0]['values'][-1]['end_time'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000').date()
first_iteration = True
while first_iteration or temp_date <= today:
  first_iteration = False
  for metric in insights['data']:
    for row in metric['values']:
      date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['end_time'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000').date() + datetime.timedelta(-1)
      result.append('%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' % (metric['id'].partition('/')[0], metric['name'], date,metric['period'], row['value']))
  insights = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(insights['paging']['next']).read())
  temp_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(insights['data'][0]['values'][-1]['end_time'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000').date()

buffer = StringIO()
temp_file = gzip.GzipFile(mode='wb', fileobj=buffer)
temp_file.write('\n'.join(result))
temp_file.close()
result = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
```

I am unclear if the app no longer works because of some change in Facebook's API or a bug on the server. I am beginning to suspect the former, since I can't find evidence of anyone else dealing with this issue.

Comment: Sorry for posting the personal information about my study at the end of the question, Igy- I did not realize this was not allowed.

Comment: Do the pagination links in the API response not work? Does it work when you explicitly request a larger range than the default? (which is 3 days as far as i know, i think you can request up to 30 days in one call)

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response! Unfortunately I am unsure precisely where my code makes the date range request- would you please point me to it in the text above?

Comment: P.S. I have tried switching the "period" from 86400 to 29 days worth of seconds and still have the same problem (I have also tried '0'). This must not be what you are suggesting though, right? Thanks.

Comment: Ah,i see you're using FQL, i misremembered this and thought it was Graph API - for FQL i think you leave period to 86400 but make separate requests moving the end_time back by a day each time
In Graph API you can specify 'since' and 'until' to fetch up to 30 days' at once: e.g. `https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE ID>/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day?since=30 days ago&until=now`

Comment: Igy- thanks so much for helping an amateur like me! I tried to change this line as you suggested but I am still only getting 3 days:                                                                  myfbfunctions.graph_api_call(access_token, oid, 'insights', {'since': 30 days, 'until': now})                                     I am very very grateful for your help!